# Get systemEnvironment['HOSTNAME'] in Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, environment-variables, hostname, spring-el

In CLI Linux I run:

```
 echo $HOSTNAME
```

and receive:

```
 alex-HP-295-G1-SFF-Business-PC
```

I try get this enviroment in java

```
 ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression expression = parser.parseExpression("systemEnvironment['HOSTNAME']");
    String message = (String) expression.getValue();
    System.out.println(message);
```

But receive the following exception:

```
 SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'systemEnvironment' cannot be found on null
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -2):

Strictly to return the `$HOSTNAME` env property, there is this solution that works:

```
System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
```

---

Alternatively, there is another work-around for this, but probably not very ideal. You could pass the hostname as a Java property when running your Java class (or Spring Boot app, or whatever you have).

```
java -DHOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME YourMainClass
```

Then, you could retrieve the Java property as:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("HOSTNAME"));
```

Comment: This is at best a workaround, with no effort to answer the issue in the question